# Connecting to website webosocket without public API

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, websocket

I don't know a lot about websockets but I know how to connect to sth like that:

```
const CHAT_URL = 'ws://echo.websocket.org/';
```

but what to do when website doesn't have public websocket API? How can I get that data?

Let's say we have website like that:
When I open dev tools, network tab and there I select WS and FRAMES, I can see new data every milisecond. Is it possible to get that data for example in my node or angular project?

At the picture you can see how it looks like in chrome dev tools.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Anything is possible, although you will need to do some work to figure out the implementations of each API on a case-by-case basis. Also please check that using their API does not go against site policy, etc.

With `cryptopia.co.nz` as an example, if we inspect the URL of the WebSocket request, we see that they are using ASP.NET's [`signalr`](https://www.asp.net/signalr) library as the backend. We can also see in the query string that a `connectionToken` is being passed, meaning that if we were to ever successfully connect to their API, we would need to come up with a valid `connectionToken`.

Looking through the docs for `signalr`, [we see that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/security/introduction-to-security#csrf) they implement some security measures, including preventing cross-domain requests. This rules out our ability to connect to the API directly from a browser client (ie. through Angular). At this point our only option is to connect to their WebSocket API from Node.js, and then proxy the data to our own browser client.

You can see this is becoming quite a deep rabbit hole. The other issue is that if they ever change their implementation at any point, your application will break. In summary, it is likely possible to connect to a private API with enough effort, but I would always look for a public API option if it was available first.